# Experts! Can python boto to load nested documents in dynamo?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto

How to index nested documents using Boto into dynamo? Or is it even possible?

I tried the following but it just  hangs...

**CASE A**

```
users.put_item(data={
    'username': 'johnd',
    'first_name': 'John',
    'last_name': 'Doe',
    'account': {'type': 'standard', 'age', '5'},
})
```

Along the same vein of nesting:

**CASE B**

```
users.put_item(data={
    'username': 'johnd',
    'first_name': 'John',
    'last_name': 'Doe',
    'account': {'type': {'level':1, 'class':'standard''}},
})
```

Can it support arrays?

**CASE C**

```
users.put_item(data={
    'username': 'johnd',
    'first_name': 'John',
    'last_name': 'Doe',
    'accounts': [{'account_name': 1}, {'account_name': 2}]
})
```

Can it support nested arrays?

**CASE D**

```
users.put_item(data={
    'username': 'johnd',
    'first_name': 'John',
    'last_name': 'Doe',
    'accounts': [{'account_name': 1, 'types':['Checking']}, {'account_name': 2, 'types':['Savings Standard', 'Savings Plus']}]
})
```

If not, are there alternatives in or outside of python? Or is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the layer1 interface in boto to put nested structures. I'm not sure if it's available in the layer2 interface yet. There's an example in this thread on the [AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=166701).